# Node.js and MongoDB sequential write causes race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, bluebird

**(Actual question: is this the correct way to make sequential writes to mongodb that does not cause a race condition and is non-blocking?)**

I am trying to accomplish a sequential write/update of documents in mongodb. The order of the operations is somewhat critical. In the sense that one operation must complete before the the next operation is sent to the database.

The way I have done it now is by using Bluebirds `Promise.mapSeries()` to loop through the request and do the correct operation to the correct collection. The database functions then return a Promise to the loop. Which i believe is the correct thing to do. When the promise is resolved then the next iteration will be fired. I believe this should also be non-blocking.

To the issue. After a bunch of inserts and the collection contains around 500k documents then the updates start failing. The status that I want to update is not reflected in the database. There is no indication from mongo that the operation failed the change is just not in the database.

The database is correctly indexed so that should not be an issue in my opinion. The I/O load is quite high. At the moment in dev-testing there is around 250 operations per second. In production that number could possibly be around 200 times bigger.

Here is a snippet of how I am doing this now:

```
Promise.mapSeries(testResults, (result) => {

  if (result.test) {

    // Save sequence results and status
    if (result.test.testSequence) {

    const coll = db.collection(collection);

    // query = result.test.id;
    // newValues = result.test;

    const options = {
            upsert: true,
            w: 'majority', // Writeconcern
            j: false,
            wtimeout: 5000 // Timeout after 5 sec
        };

    return coll.updateOne(query, newValues, options);

  }
  else if(result.test.singleTest {
    // Do pretty much the same as above
  }
}
```

Thankful for opinions :)

Comment: apart from the syntax errors, it looks OK, of course, there's no error checking/handling in your code

Comment: Yes there might  well be syntax errors there as I just took a snippet and also compacted the code as much as possible as all these things happen in different functions and files.